# Building a C/C++ project without using Makefiles

Tags: c++, build

I have a project containing C/C++ files. I'd like to build it without using `make`. What are my options? I'd like cross platform solutions if possible.

Comment: cmake, scons, maven pick your poison...

Comment: Technically, cmake uses make files, depending on your target compiler and other options - but you don't have to write them yourself, which is a big plus. Which shouldn't be read as meaning that cmake is trivial to use - the cmake way is a good way, but the initiation can be painful.

Comment: @Steve314, yeah I wanted to list three and couldn't think of another... ;)

Comment: @Steve314, yes you don't have to write the Makefile, but you have the write the Cmake script... I'm not sure which one is more painful

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929846/what-is-currently-the-best-build-system

Comment: @DavidM - well, for one thing, cmake doesn't consider spaces and tabs to be semantically different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [SCons](http://scons.org) and it is very good.

> SCons is an Open Source software construction tool—that is, a next-generation build tool. Think of SCons as an improved, cross-platform substitute for the classic Make utility with integrated functionality similar to autoconf/automake and compiler caches such as ccache. In short, SCons is an easier, more reliable and faster way to build software.

I've also looked at [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) but have not seriously used it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're always going to need some way to invoke the compiler.  If it's a trivial project, you can usually just stick all the .C filenames on the command line of the compiler and get some kind of output.

Or you can use a batch file / shell script instead of a makefile, but it would be less 'cross-platform' than a makefile and much less useful.

You should probably explain your motivations more clearly.

Comment: It's not that I don't have experience with makefiles, it's just I don't like the syntax one bit. I find it so hard to mantain, let alone explain to new people what $< $* are :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're going to use Boost anyways (right?) Boost.Jam might be an option.

Comment: I thought there were only 2-3 people in the world who know how to write bjam files. Is that not so?

Answer (score 2):

I already used [WAF](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) in some of my projects and it worked out quite well.

If you are familiar with python...

Answer (score 1):

A common alternative is to write python scripts to compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

How are you editing you code? Can that system also build it for you?

Visual Studio, Eclipse, XCode, KDevelop?  :-)

Comment: Partially, yes. We're compiling for multiple platforms. When we do it for Windows, VS is used. But for other platforms, and unit testing, we're relying on makefiles.