# Build system for R

Tags: r, waf, build-system

I've got a large data analysis project containing dozens of R scripts that depend in complicated ways on each other and so I thought it would be a good idea to formalize all these dependencies and set the project in a build system that runs things in the correct order and re-runs anything that changes or anything that's downstream from things that change.

But even after some hours worth of googling I haven't found any build systems that are custom-made for R (though there are [plenty for more genreal purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929846/what-is-currently-the-best-build-system)). I've previously worked with [waf](https://github.com/waf-project/waf) to organize data analysis projects in Python and know I could use waf to run R scripts as well. But having to manage a whole Python environment just to run some R scripts seems clunky.

What are other people using to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe it is worth to reorganize the project first, as "containing dozens of R scripts that depend in complicated ways on each other" seems pretty tough to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called "[GRANBase](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GRANBase/index.html)" that is capable of doing something similar to what you're referring to. It's an R package management & build tool, so if your scripts are put into R package(s), you could probably make use of it.